# What is the idiomatic way to alter a vector that is stored in an atomized map?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have an atom called `app-state` that holds a map. It looks like this:

```
{:skills [{:id 1 :text "hi"} {:id 2 :text "yeah"}]}
```

What is the idiomatic way to remove the element inside the vector with `:id = 2` ? The result would look like:

```
{:skills [{:id 1 :text "hi"}]}
```

...
So far, I have this:

```
(defn new-list [id]
   (remove #(= id (:id %)) (get @app-state :skills)))

swap! app-state assoc :skills (new-list 2)
```

It works, but I feel like this isn't quite right. I think it could be something like:

```
swap! app-state update-in [:skills] remove #(= id (:id %))
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(swap! state update :skills (partial remove (comp #{2} :id)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(defn new-list [app-state-map id]
      (assoc app-state-map :skills (into [] (remove #(= id (:id %)) (:skills app-state-map)))))

(swap! app-state new-list 2)
```

`swap!` will pass the current value of the atom to the function you supply it. There's no need to dereference it yourself in the function.

See the [docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/swap!) on `swap!` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
(def skills {:skills [{:id 1 :text "hi"} {:id 2 :text "yeah"}]})

(defn remove-skill [id]
  (update skills :skills (fn [sks] (vec (remove #(= id (:id %)) sks)))))
```

You would then be able to call say `(remove-skill 1)` and see that only the other one (skill with :id of 2) is left.

I like your way better. And this would need to be adapted for use against an atom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`filter`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter) to do this.  Here is a function that takes an id and the map and let's you filter out anything that doesn't match your criteria.  Of course, you can make the `#()` reader macro check for equality rather than inequality depending on your needs.

```
user=> (def foo {:skills [{:id 1 :text "hi"} {:id 2 :text "yeah"}]})
#'user/foo
user=> (defn bar [id sklz] (filter #(not= (:id %) id) (:skills sklz)))
#'user/bar
user=> (bar 1 foo)
({:id 2, :text "yeah"})
user=> (bar 2 foo)
({:id 1, :text "hi"})
```